# Python return value

Tags: python, function, return-value

I have a global variable `global_a` and the function to determine the value

```
# long Syntax
def assignement_a():
  global_a = len(xyz)
  return global_a
```

The point is to return the value to caller and simultaneously assign the value to the global to saved for further use, so I need something like this

```
# shorter syntax
def assignement_a():
  return global_a = len(xyz)
```

Is there a short syntax solution in python?

Comment: Two lines of code are too long…?

Comment: Let the lambda battle begin!

Comment: neither of those two actually modifies a global variable

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, the correct version of "long syntax" is:

```
def assignement_a():
  global global_a
  global_a = len(xyz)
  return global_a
```

As for the "short syntax" I don't see why it would be necessary here. Maybe it can be made shorter using a lambda, but that might just obscure the purpose of this function. Further using globals is not really a best practice anyway and is why Python requires you to be explicit about it (that and the way Python handles variable scope)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the global variable from the caller function or statement for ex:

```
global_a=0
var1=0
xyz="stackoverflow"
def assignement_a():
  return len(xyz)


def test():  
 global global_a
 global var1
 var1=global_a=assignement_a()
 print(var1)

test()
print(var1)
print(global_a)
```

Like test method is a caller and thus return value is assigned to global variable or it can be use for further process.

Comment: @UnholySheep see Edited

Comment: You still have wrong indentation on your last 3 lines. Also this does not do what OP asked for - he specifically wanted `assignement_a` to return a value **and** modify the global variable

Comment: @UnholySheep I just posted one of the possible answers.